# Calculating interior angles of quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, polygons

stupid question... but:

I've a polygon which has the points $(a_x,a_y),(b_x,b_y),(c_x,c_y), (d_x,d_y)$

How can I calculate each interior angle of this quadrilateral? I know that in sum, it has to be $360^\circ$.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know about vectors, the dot product can help you out here.

Recall $\textbf{a.b}=a b \cos(\theta)$. Rearrange this to get your desired result.

Comment: cos^-1(a.b/ab) = alpha - like this?

Comment: Yes. So now just find the vectors which "make up" the quadrilateral and then the appropriate dot products and magnitudes

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).  Let $p=|a-b|, q=|a-c|, r=|b-c|$ so you have drawn the diagonal from $b$ to $c$ and have a triangle with side lengths $p,q,r$.  Then if $\theta$ is the angle at $a$, you have $r^2=p^2+q^2-2pq \cos \theta$

Comment: Sorry, this looks very strange to me. Is there no "easier" solution to calculate all interior angles? I don't need to know the position of my angles. All i need to know is: "87, 93, 70,110". I know the exact positions, I know the length and I know the  area and perimeter

Comment: @Dalanie91:  the dot product that john mentions is another way to get $\cos \theta$.  Whether it is easier or not, I'm not sure.  I don't know any way that doesn't involve an inverse trig function.